# Continuous data extraction from url with data manipulation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, real-time, data-extraction, continuous

I want to create a simple script that does two things:

1. Downloads some bitcoin price data every hour from a url and stores it locally in one csv that would be updated every hour with new data.
   With help of pandas I would read this csv file, do some calculations, like Standard Deviation and variance and moving average, and write a new file with these new fields added(stddev and var).
2. Every minute, I would query a url for the same data as in point 1, but with a minute resolution, store it a separate csv file which would be deleted once a day or so.
3. Every minute, I would compare the minute data against the calculation made on hourly data like for example: `if minute_price < moving_average do something` (send email for example)

I'm new to Python, but I can do some things. I have the script that extracts the data from url, does all the needed calculations in pandas and stores the data to the csv files, but what I don't know ho to do is the continuous url querying for the minute data and making this queried data available for comparison.
I wrote a small code that extracts data every 5 seconds and writes it to a list, but it uses the `While True` statement, so it never ends and as consequence I can never access the the list with prices since it sits inside that script and the only way to access that list with data is by interrupting the script.

Any idea on how I could operate with the data that comes every minute and compare it to the data that sits in my csv files?

Thanks.

Data extraction script:

```
import time
import request
import json


url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD'
def data_extract(url):
    l1 = list()
    while True:
        r3 = requests.get(url)
        print(r3.json())
        l1.append(r3.json()['USD'])
        time.sleep(5 - (time.time() % 5))

data_extract(url)
```

Comment: you need to make this into a script that has a `main` function and then throw your time requirements into `cron`

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to check what is `cron`. As of main function. I already use it, but nothing changes.